# Flutter_downloader issue web app not running

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Description:

My Flutter application is designed to seamlessly function across both mobile and web platforms. While I have successfully integrated the Flutter Downloader package, I have encountered a challenge. Although the mobile version operates flawlessly, I am currently facing an obstacle with the web version, as it refuses to run. Your assistance in resolving this web-specific issue would be greatly appreciated.

Expected Behavior

The intended functionality for my application involves enabling a download feature exclusively for the mobile platform while excluding this feature for the web platform. I had assumed that by utilizing a package intended solely for mobile use, I could easily hide the download button when the application runs on the web.

This is my error log

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on Edge in debug mode...
    main.dart:1
    This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:60595/SpKN4cj70W8=/ws
    Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60595/SpKN4cj70W8=/ws
    Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:60595/SpKN4cj70W8=/ws
    The webOnlyWarmupEngine API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `bootstrapEngine` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
    The webOnlySetPluginHandler API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `setPluginHandler` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
    [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Localization initialized
    Error: UnimplementedError
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
    lib/ui/window.dart 181:5                                                      getCallbackHandle
    packages/flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart 55:38                         initialize
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5            _async
    packages/flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart 44:33                         initialize
    packages/kleely/main.dart 35:27                                               main$
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
    dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                    handleValue
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                    handleValueCallback
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                    _propagateToListeners
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 641:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:7                                     callback
    dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
    dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
    The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
    Restarted application in 310ms.
    Error: UnimplementedError
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
    lib/ui/window.dart 181:5                                                      getCallbackHandle
    packages/flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart 55:38                         initialize
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5            _async
    packages/flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart 44:33                         initialize
    packages/kleely/main.dart 35:27                                               main$
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
    dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                    handleValue
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                    handleValueCallback
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                    _propagateToListeners
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 641:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:7                                     callback
    dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
    dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
    The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` inst
```

This is my version:

```
    Flutter 3.13.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    Framework • revision efbf63d9c6 (6 days ago) • 2023-08-15 21:05:06 -0500
    Engine • revision 1ac611c64e
    Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
    name: kleely
    description: A new Flutter project.
    publish_to: "none"
    version: 0.1.0
    android_package: com.kleelycom.kleely
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.19.6 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
      # firebase
      firebase_core: ^2.15.0
      firebase_auth: ^4.7.1
      cloud_firestore: ^4.8.3
      firebase_storage: ^11.2.5
    
      # other
      http: ^0.13.6
      intl: ^0.18.0
      permission_handler: ^10.4.3
      dartz:
    
      # route
      path_provider: ^2.1.0
      auto_route: ^5.0.2
    
      # Generators
      username_generator: ^1.3.0
      uuid: ^3.0.7
    
      # style
      flex_color_scheme: ^7.0.5
      flutter_carousel_widget: ^2.0.4
      flutter_screenutil: ^5.7.0
      flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
      google_fonts: ^4.0.4
      shimmer: ^3.0.0
      curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
      percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
      infinite_carousel: ^1.0.2
      intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.3+1
      loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+4
      widget_and_text_animator: ^1.0.0
    
      # localization
      easy_localization: ^3.0.2
    
      # network and overlay
      connectivity_plus: ^4.0.2
      overlay_support: ^2.1.0
    
      # video and image
      appinio_video_player: ^1.2.1
      image_picker: ^1.0.2
      image_cropper: ^1.4.1
      flutter_downloader: ^1.11.1
    
      # storage
      hive: ^2.2.3
      hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
    
      # state management & dependency injection
      get: ^4.6.5
      get_it: ^7.6.0
      bloc: ^8.1.2
      flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
      provider: ^6.0.5
      blurry_modal_progress_hud: ^1.1.1
      firebase_performance: ^0.9.2+5
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
      flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
      auto_route_generator: ^5.0.2
      build_runner: ^2.3.3
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
      hive_generator: ^2.0.1
    
    flutter_icons:
      android: true
      ios: true
      image_path: "assets/logos/icon.png"
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
    
      assets:
        - assets/logos/KleeliLogo.png
        - assets/logos/KleeliIcon.ico
        - assets/icons/1.png
        - assets/icons/2.png
        - assets/icons/3.png
        - assets/icons/4.png
        - assets/icons/biology.png
        - assets/icons/chemistry.png
        - assets/icons/physics.png
        - assets/icons/math.png
        - assets/translations/
        - assets/images/c.jpg
        - assets/audio/loading.mp3
```

Comment: For security, web browsers limit access to all system resources, like the file system. The best I was able to do was to create a fake link to the file I wanted to download, and trigger a click on it. That makes the browser activate its download process, allowing the user to select a location. But make sure the browser knows it's a plain file that won't be opened by a handling application.

Comment: @JohnBayko the problem for me is i don't want to be able to download on web, but with having that package and the packages supports only IOS and android, my web version of the application is not running, i only see a white screen.

Comment: I assume you check `Platform` from `'dart:io'` to skip adding any components and avoid initializing the `Downloader` package, yes? What is the code that produces the error actually doing?

Comment: @JohnBayko you just gave me the right idea how to fix it and i was lost in this mess for soo long, thank you soo much i just added this and all my problems went away:
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await FlutterDownloader.initialize();
  }

Answer (score 0):

please try my method sorry if it doesn't work,
when flutterfire configure , you uncheck web , you should check everything from

- android
- web
- iOS
- windows
  use it all

It's possible that the website you are using for Firebase is running